# IF statement based on row position

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have raw data which looks like below -

```
Name  Index Flag
Open    1   1
1       1   1
2       1   1
Closure 1   2
1       1   2
Closure 2   1
1       2   1
2       2   1
Closure 2   2
Open    3   1
1       3   1
Closure 3   2
```

I want the "flag" variable to be created based on 'name' variable. By unique values of Index variables, I want flag to have 1 if Name = "Open" and retain 1 until name = "Closure" then return 2. But there is a twist - if (any value or "Closure") is at starting of index variable, it should return 1.  **In the above example, refer rows 6 through 9 to understand the problem.** The above table can be reproduced using the code below -

```
data = read.table(text="
Name    Index
'Open'  1
                  1 1
                  2 1
                  'Closure' 1
                  1 1
                  'Closure' 2
                  1 2
                  2 2
                  'Closure' 2
                  'Open'    3
                  1 3
                  'Closure' 3

                  ", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second occurance of `Closure` in `Index == 2` have `Flag == 1` based on your description: *if (any value or "Closure") is at starting of index variable, it should return 1 until 'name' variable has different value*?

Comment: It should be 1 only. Thanks for highlighting. I have rephrased the requirement.

Comment: I don't understand your description for the rules, but `setDT(data); data[, f := rleid(cumsum(Name=="Closure")), by=Index]` gives the output for the example.